# linux : how to compress each file individually in an archive tar/cpio/...other

Tags: linux, compression, archive

I'm searching how to make an archive with each file into it compressed.

For example : fic1.txt fic2.log fic3.srt

I want to make an archive "fics.tar" with each file individually compressed into it, and files renamed.

The archive should contain : fic1.txt.gz fic2.log.gz fic3.srt.gz

Problem with tar/pax/cpio programs is that we can't do this directly, **and i don't want to compress the files (or copies of them) on the hard drive**, it has to be done in memory with a buffer in order to use it with pipes.

example on serverX : ./compress_and_tar fic1.txt fic2.log fic3.srt | ssh server1 "tar -x"

Result : fic1.txt.gz fic2.log.gz fic3.srt.gz on **server1**, only hard drive readings on the serverX, zero writings.

Have you an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I need to transfer files from one server to an other by ssh, but with only one flow : only one connection to the destination server (if i open 1 ssh connection by file, transfer time will explose). 


Files have to be compressed on the destination server. That's why I do the compression **before** transferring : files are smaller => transfer time is reduced


But if I compress the entire archive before transferring, i have do decompress the archive, and then re-compress the files... not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use a better suited archive type. Either zip (more portable) or 7z (better compression). These formats always compress each member separately.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with zip or 7zip. It only compress files and it does not make an archive 

I don't want and archive (zip/tar or other) compressed, but and an archive with files into it compressed